# PHP for each loop that applies different CSS stlyes

Tags: php, for-loop

I would like to make a link bold if the the URL ends with a certain ending:

http://url.com/test#style1

http://url.com/test#style2

...and so on up to #style15

Would it be best to do this with PHP or Javascript?
Could I make the following into a loop that runs through #style1 - #style15?

```
<?php
$URL = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

if ($URL == "http://url.com/test#style1") { ?>

<style>.a1 {font-weight:bold;} </style>

<?
}
else if ($URL == "http://url.com/test#style2") { 
?>

<style>.a2 {font-weight:bold;} </style>

<?
}?>
```

Comment: PHP never see the fragment so you'll have to do this with JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access hash in php i.e. like here "#style1" from URL, for this you have to you javascript.

Here is the solution in Javascript:

```
<script>
if (window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    if (hash.length != 0) { 
      for(i=1; i<=15; i++){
          if(("style"+i) == hash){
             /* Used jQuery here */
             $(".a"+i).css("font-weight", "bold");
          }
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has no access to part or URL behind hash (#), so only way is JavaScript.

You can access to this part of URL by `location.hash`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [CSS](http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/) to apply the styles. It can easily read the final characters of an an attribute(E.G $=) and apply appropriate styling without the use of PHP or Javascript.

```
a[href$="1"] { font-weight:bold; }
```